# The character of a direct sum of representations is the sum of their characters

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

The character of a direct sum of representations $p \oplus p'$ is the sum $\chi + \chi'$ of their characters. If we let $p'' = p \oplus p'$ for all $g \in G$ where $G$ is a finite group on which the representations are defined on, then the matrix of $p_g''$ will have a a block diagonal form and its easy then to see the result.

However, how can I do this without fixing a basis?

Comment: I'm not really sure that there is a way without basis. Maybe you can use this argument: $p''_g \in GL(V\oplus W)$ and it is equal to:
\begin{equation}
p''_g = i_V \circ p_g \circ \pi_V + i_W \circ p'_g \circ \pi_W
\end{equation}
where $i_V:V\rightarrow V\oplus W$ is the inclusion map and $\pi_V:V\oplus W\rightarrow V$ the projection map. Now, thanks to the linearity of the trace, you have only to proof that $tr(i_V \circ p_g \circ \pi_V) = tr(p_g)$ but I don't know a way to proof formally this statement without using bases. Maybe using the canonical isomorphism $V\otimes V^* = End(V)$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $k$ be a field, and consider all vector spaces to be finite-dimensional. There are many ways to characterise the trace of a linear operator $T \colon V \to V$. Here are some of them:

1. $\operatorname{tr}_V \colon \operatorname{End}(V) \to k$ is the unique $k$-linear map such that for every projection $p \in \operatorname{End}(V)$ (a *projection* means that $p^2 = p$) we have $\operatorname{tr}_V(p) = \dim \operatorname{im}(p)$.
2. Let $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$ be the eigenvalues (with multiplicity) of $T$ in some algebraic closure of $k$. Then $\operatorname{tr}_V(p) = \lambda_1 + \cdots + \lambda_n$.
3. Regard $T$ as an element of $V \otimes V^*$ by inverting the canoonical isomorphism $V \otimes V^* \to \operatorname{End}_k(V)$. Then $\operatorname{tr}_V(T) = \operatorname{ev}(T)$, where $\operatorname{ev} \colon V \otimes V^* \to k$ is the evaluation map $\operatorname{ev}(v \otimes f) = f(v)$.

You can interpret (3) in terms of matrix coordinates. Let $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ be a basis of $V$, with dual basis $v_1^*, \ldots, v_n^*$ of $V^*$. Then $v_i \otimes v_j^*$ gets mapped under the canonical isomorphism to the matrix with a 1 in the $(i, j)$ spot. Clearly $\operatorname{ev}(v_i \otimes v_j^*) = \delta_{ij}$, and so we recover the usual definition of trace as "sum of the diagonal elements of a matrix".

So pick your favourite characterisation above, and prove that if $V = U \oplus W$, so that $T_{UU}$, $T_{UW}$, $T_{WU}$, $T_{WW}$ are the components of $T$ on this decomposition, that $\operatorname{tr}_V(T) = \operatorname{tr}_U(T_{UU}) + \operatorname{tr}_W(T_{WW})$ (the off-diagonal components do not matter).